# Discord.py syntax error from passing 3 arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm currently working on a small discord bot and I received the following error:

```
async def redeemkey(ctx, *, member, *, key):
                                    ^
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def redeemkey(ctx, *, member, *, key):
    if key[keys] == True:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='authenticated')
        await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

I've tried switching things up in the arguments but just can't seem to get it right.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can have only one `*` in there, at the end of all positional arguments.

Comment: so remove the first one?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: i have a dictionary of keys, if a user redeems one with something like !reedeemkey 1895hjfjh57v5, it gives them a role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to give a member a role if they provide the correct key, you do not need `*` in your function. We can grab member from [`ctx.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author), and get `key` from the command.

Instead of using `member.server.roles`, you can use `ctx.guild.roles`. Server was changed to guild in [v1.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild) of `discord.py`.

If `keys` is your dictionary, `keys[key]` should be used and not `key[keys]`.

```
@client.command()
async def redeemkey(ctx, key):
    if key in keys:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='authenticated')
        await client.add_roles(ctx.author, role)
```